# Three.js issue at edges of tiled texture using MeshFaceMaterial

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping, tiling

I am trying to tile the texture from multiple images onto a plane geometry using MeshFaceMaterial. Every thing works fine, except for a blurry edge forming in between tiles.
[image: Screenshot of image].

```
        var textureArray = [];
        var tileColumns = 2;
        var tileRows = 1;
        textureArray[0] = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./test3.jpg');
        textureArray[1] = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./test4.jpg');

        var faceCountPerTileX = 2 * widthSegments/tileColumns;
        var faceCountPerTileY = heightSegments/tileRows;
        var faceCountX = 2 * widthSegments;
        var faceCountY = heightSegments;         

        for(var tileIndexY = 0; tileIndexY < tileRows; tileIndexY++){
            for(var tileIndexX = 0; tileIndexX < tileColumns; tileIndexX++){

                var index = tileIndexY * tileColumns + tileIndexX;
            textureArray[index].wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            textureArray[index].wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;  
            textureArray[index].repeat.set(tileColumns,tileRows);                    

                materialContainer[tileIndexY * tileColumns + tileIndexX] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map: textureArray[tileIndexY * tileColumns + tileIndexX],
                    overdraw: true,
                    ambient: 0xffffff
                }); 

                for(var faceIndexY = tileIndexY * faceCountPerTileY; faceIndexY < (tileIndexY+1) * faceCountPerTileY; faceIndexY++){                
                    for(var faceIndexX = tileIndexX * faceCountPerTileX; faceIndexX < (tileIndexX+1) * faceCountPerTileX; faceIndexX++){
                        g.faces[faceIndexY * faceCountX + faceIndexX].materialIndex = tileIndexY * tileColumns + tileIndexX;
                    }  
                }       
            }
        }        

    var mat = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialContainer);

    var obj = new THREE.Mesh(g, mat);
```

I have tried all known solutions, i have even tried writing a custom shader and using ShaderMaterial. But no luck, can some help me out to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you set the texture mode of the invidual textures in your set to *repeat*.

This seems wrong, the individual textures do not repeat, they are displayed only once. Setting a texture to repeat causes the right side of the texture to "blend through" on the left (and vice versa), causing visible seams like the one on your screenshot.

Comment: I tried without repeating, But the problem is as plane geometry is uv mapped from 0 to 1, the texture on the left is taking half from first image and on the the right a half from second image. In order to manage for the uv mapping i used repeat.